# Property 'paginate' does not exist on type 'Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to apply mongoose paginate in my nextjs project and for some reason I can't make it work out tried most of the ways reccomended online couldn't make it work

Model-

```
import mongoose, { InferSchemaType, Schema, models } from 'mongoose'
import paginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2'

const CityImageSchema = new Schema({
  fileName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fileContentType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fileSize: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  fileSha1: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

const CitySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  cityImage: {
    type: CityImageSchema,
    required: false, // TODO: Handle image storage
  },
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
})

CitySchema.plugin(paginate) // <-- Add the pagination plugin here
const Cities = models.City || mongoose.model('City', CitySchema)
type CityType = InferSchemaType<typeof CitySchema>

export type { CityType }
export default Cities
```

Controller-

```
import {
  createCity,
  fetchAllActiveCities,
  fetchCityById,
  removeCity,
  updateCity,
} from '@/application/cities/cityService'
import withMongo from '@/services/infrastructure/database/mongodb'
import { GenericResponse } from '@/types/api'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const getAllCities = withMongo(async (req) => {
  // Extracting parameters from URL with default values
  const page = req.query.page || '1'
  const pageSize = req.query.pageSize || '10'

  // Convert parameters to numbers
  const pageNumber = parseInt(page, 10)
  const pageSizeNumber = parseInt(pageSize, 10)

  // Check for invalid numbers
  if (isNaN(pageNumber) || isNaN(pageSizeNumber)) {
    return NextResponse.json<GenericResponse<any>>(
      {
        message: 'Invalid page or pageSize',
      },
      { status: 400 }
    )
  }

  const cities = await fetchAllActiveCities(pageNumber, pageSizeNumber)

  return NextResponse.json<GenericResponse<any>>(
    {
      message: cities.message,
      data: cities.data,
      pagination: cities.pagination, // Pass pagination data to the response
    },
    { status: cities.code }
  )
})
```

Service-

```
import { CityRequest, CityResponse } from '@/controller/cities/types'
import Cities from '@/domain/cities/citySchema'
import { ResponseMessage } from '@/types/api'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

export const fetchAllActiveCities = async (
  page: number,
  pageSize: number
): Promise<CityResponse> => {
  try {
    const query = { isActive: true } // Filter for active cities
    const options = { page, limit: pageSize }
    const cities = await Cities.paginate(query, options)

    return {
      message: ResponseMessage.SUCCESS,
      code: 200,
      data: cities.docs, // Access paginated cities from `.docs`
      pagination: cities.pagination, // Access pagination information
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      message: error || ResponseMessage.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERR,
      code: 500,
    }
  }
}
```

In service I get the error - Property 'paginate' does not exist on type 'Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>'.ts(2339)
and even when i test it it gives -     "message": "Error database connection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'page')"
any guidance would be appreciated